# How do I fix the `Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.dll` file not found error when building Maui sample source code?

Tags: .net, maui

I built the sample source code at [Maui Repository - Essentials](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main/src/Essentials/samples/Samples) and get the error message:

> <**path**>/maui/.nuspec/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.targets(457,9): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.DetectInvalidResourceOutputFilenamesTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly <**path**>/maui/.nuspec/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.dll. Could not load file or assembly '<**path**>/maui/.nuspec/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified. [<**path**>/maui/src/Essentials/samples/Samples/Essentials.Sample.csproj]
> <**path**>/maui/.nuspec/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.targets(457,9): error MSB4062:  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [<**path**>/maui/src/Essentials/samples/Samples/Essentials.Sample.csproj]

**NOTE**: <**path**> is the local folder that contain the sample source code.

I installed Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk via .NET CLI command:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk --version 6.0.101-preview.10.2068`

Rebuilt and I get same errors. Can someone tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: Yep getting this error on .net Maui (June 2022 GA or preview 3 who knows) It seems to be due to not being able to access a splash screen file called bicycle.svg. Probably needs to be just called splash.svg (as in the appicon.svg)

Comment: Ahh it was, the splash screen must be named spash.svg and also update the .csproj Possibly not related to original issue, but may be useful to someone. :)